# Read application.conf configuration in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following data source configured in `application.conf` that I use to run Slick statements.

I need to access the same database through an OLAP engine that will use the same user and password.

Since it's already configured, I'd like to get these two from there, is it possible to read `application.conf` from Scala? I know I can read the physical file, but is there a library to get the parsed data?

```
## JDBC Datasource
# ~~~~~
#

dbConfig = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
  driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
  user=root
  password=xxxx
}
```

Comment: Which version of play are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/typesafehub/config ( in general )

Comment: As linked by @m-z typesafe config is what you need. But if you are using Play 2.5, you can just inject the configuration where needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with play, you simply inject the configuration like this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration

class Something @Inject()(configuration: Configuration) {
  val url: Option[String] = configuration.getString("dbConfig.url")
  val keepAliveConnection: Option[Boolean] = configuration.getBoolean("dbConfig.keepAliveConnection")

  ...
}
```

Also see [Configuration API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration) on how to get your properties in various types and formats.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I would just add that values return in an `Option`. Is it a good practice to store my own values in application.conf, using it as a properties file?

Comment: Added option types for clarification. And yes, this is good practice. [Production Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration) might be useful for you too.

Comment: Maybe add to your answer:
Imports: import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration